# How to get this type of line for code in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

i want to know how to get thie type of line eclipse what is shortcut key for this ?

[image]

Comment: i am the develope apps in android so i want to show indent lines but don't know how

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566569/vertical-line-between-matching-curly-braces-for-java-in-eclipse
Please try searching before posting a question, I found this in 2 minutes.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you need this, it's a very strong indicator that your code needs to be refactored into much smaller methods (properly indented).

Comment: i got my solution http://editbox.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

`Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Editors` > `Text Editors` -- and you can customize your editor the way you want it to be.

Here it is the **Indent Guide** which causes the issue. Disable it and close all open Java editors, as it is not picked up dynamically.

[image: Eclipse Indent Guide]

Comment: i got my solution http://editbox.sourceforge.net/